# How can I create tmp folder in lua?

Tags: lua, tmp

How can I create temporary folder in lua?
I mean, like that i can create tmp file with `os.tmpname` , I looking for a way to create temporary directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using just the standard library: Lua's standard library is very limited because it is based only on C's standard library for maximum portability. There is `os.tmpname` or `io.tmpfile` but neither can be used for creating a temporary directory. For creating a temporary directory, you need more powerful libraries such as LuaPosix which provides [`posix.stdlib.mkdtemp(templ)`](https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.stdlib.html#mkdtemp).

Alternatively, you could try invoking commands to create a temporary directory using `os.execute` or `io.popen`, but this would be even less portable and presumably also less efficient.

Comment: can please help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74943547/should-i-check-the-returned-value-in-this-case ?